# Classes and Concrete Classes

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

I want know the difference between these classes, In my app, i need to set some parameters and pass objects through methods. I have some interfaces with only methods (Mostly DAO/Factory methods). I have some question around my code.

- Should I use only Interfaces and Concrete classes?
- Or Use Classes (With Getter and Setter) and Implement only Methods?.
- Should I mix them ? is a bad practice?.

Interface:

```
public interface Animal {
  void roar();
}
```

Concrete Class with implemented methods from Interface

```
public Lion implements Animal {
@overrride
 void roar(){
    //roar like lion!
  }
}
```

Concrete class: I have this one for Construct Objects to make DAO Operations.

```
public class Lion {
  private String lionName;
  getter and setter...
  void roar(){
 //Roar like Lion.
 }
}
```

Abstract:

```
abstract class Lion {
  abstract public void abstractRoar();
}
```

Thanks in advance , like always your help is really appreciated.

Comment: You can't have method implementations within an interface

Comment: Anyways, I think you're missing `abstract class` example

Comment: @cricket_007 Ohh Sorry , My bad. Edited.

Comment: Method implementation inside interface is supported from Java 8. Am I wrong @cricket_007?

Comment: abstract method can't have body in the `abstract Lion` class. It will be implemented in the classes that extend the abstract class

Comment: Your question looks like related to practise of using design patterns. I suggest you to read the `creational design patterns` from [This Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/)

Comment: @MdJohirulIslam Thank you very much. I'll do.

Comment: interfaces vs abstract classes is not an either/or question. It depends on the problem (and therefore I consider the question too broad). For your example, either will work.

Comment: @MdJohirulIslam I disagree. Patterns are not a substitute to knowing when to use an interface and when to use abstract classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it right, your question is:

> Do I need to implement an interface every time I create a class?

The answer is no. Interface is only used for abstraction. If several classes share common methods, use an interface will simplify the code.

For more about interface (when should I use, how do I use), please refer to the book Effective Java (Item 19). Here is a link:

[Effective Java Item 19](http://jtechies.blogspot.com/2012/07/item-19-use-interfaces-only-to-define.html)

Hope that solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks , Im looking the Book.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this:

Class Users:

```
public class Users {

private int userId;
private String userPassword;
private int userProfile;
private String userName;    
private String userPosition;
private int userCencos;
private String userOffice;

public Users(int userId, String userPassword, int userProfile, String userName, String userPosition, int userCencos, String userOffice) {
    Constructor..
}

public String getUserOffice() {
    return userOffice;
}
more getter/setter ...
```

Interface:

```
public interface UserDAOInterface {

    public int insert(Users user) throws SQLException;
    more DAO Operations...
}
```

DAO User:

```
public class UserDAOConcrete implements UserDAOInterface {

private int result;    
public PreparedStatement query;

@Override
public Users login(int userId, String password) throws NumberFormatException , SQLException{

    SQL sql = new SQL();
    try {            

        PreparedStatement loginQuery = sql.createPStatement(cf.SELECT_USER_BY_LOGIN_DATA);
        loginQuery.setInt(1, userId);
        loginQuery.setString(2, password);
        System.out.println(loginQuery.toString());

        try {
            ResultSet resultSet = loginQuery.executeQuery();
            if (!resultSet.isBeforeFirst()) {
                loginQuery.close();
                sql.dbConection().close();
                throw new NullPointerException("Usuario No encontrado");
            }
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Users newLoggedUser = new Users();

                newLoggedUser.setUserId(resultSet.getInt("UserId"));
                newLoggedUser.setUserCencos(resultSet.getInt("CostCenter_CostCenterId"));
                newLoggedUser.setUserProfile(resultSet.getInt("Profiles_ProfileId"));                    
                newLoggedUser.setUserName(resultSet.getString("UserName"));
                newLoggedUser.setUserPosition(resultSet.getString("UserPosition"));
                newLoggedUser.setUserOffice(resultSet.getString("UserOffice"));
                resultSet.close();
                loginQuery.close();
                sql.dbConection().close();
                return newLoggedUser;
            }
        } catch (SQLException | NullPointerException | NumberFormatException e) {                
            throw e;
        } finally {
            try {
                loginQuery.close();
                sql.dbConection().close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQL Error: " + e);
            }
        }
        return null;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("SQL Error: " + ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

DAOFactory:

```
public class UserDAOFactory {

public static UserDAOConcrete getUserDAO(String type) { 
    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("user")) {
        return new UserDAOConcrete();
    } else {
        return new UserDAOConcrete();
    }
}
```

Call method:

```
UserDAOConcrete userDAO = UserDAOFactory.getUserDAO("user");
Users userData = userDAO.login(Integer.parseInt(loginUserId.getText()), String.valueOf(userLoginPassword.getPassword()));    
//Do whatever you need with the Object userData.
```

As you can see I have a mix of Class with Getter/setter and Interfaces , Is working fine , should I do all my code like this?.

Answer (score -1):

They each have distinct use cases that you need to decide from to see which fits your needs better.

The general purpose of an `interface` is to define a set of related methods that can be implemented and reused across several/many classes. For your example with animals, in my opinion, I would make `Animal` a parent class to be extended by classes such as `Lion`, `Tiger`, `Bear`, etc. An interface for this use case could be something along the lines of `Noises`. Each animal may have different noises, however, they all **do make noise**. The interface could have `growl`, `roar`, `sniff`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Can I  use my Class `Lion` , with its getter/setter to construct objects and work around with the interfaces?. Or do I need to set the instance variables in the class that implements `Animal` ?.

Comment: @JuanSebastianOsorio I'm a little confused by what you mean. You need to set a class's instance variables, within that class either in the constructor or through setters after instantiation.

Comment: I just posted one part of the code. Thanks for your help.